# How to import data.table indexing functionality?

Tags: r, data.table, roxygen2

What is the proper way to import the data.table indexing functionality `A[ , , by = ...]` into my package?

Should I have my roxygen docs contain:

`importFrom data.table [.data.table`

Comment: Would it be too cumbersome to import the whole `data.table` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to import just `data.table` function and `[` method will be correctly dispatched.

`subdt/R/mysubdt.R`

```
mysubdt = function(x) {
    stopifnot(class(x)[1L]=="data.table", c("s","g","v") %in% names(x), is.logical(x[["s"]]))
    x[s==TRUE, sum(v), by=g]
}
```

`subdt/NAMESPACE`

```
importFrom(data.table, data.table)
export(mysubdt)
```

After build and install package (you don't need `::` if you load data.table too, code assumes you didn't):

```
library(subdt)
x = data.table::data.table(
    s = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
    g = c("a","b","a","b"),
    v = 1:4/10
)
mysubdt(x)
#   g  V1
#1: a 0.1
#2: b 0.6
```